# how to call other functions in flat list render function?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I have a `Flatlist` which i call other functions inside that render function

```
   otherFunc(){
       alert('some thing')
   }
   item(data){
      return(
          //...something..
          {this.otherFunc()} <<<<<<<<<problem is here...its undefined
      );
   }
   render() {
       <FlatList
            ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
            data={this.state.foods}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.Item}
            horizontal
            onEndReached={(x) => { this.loadMore() }}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      />
   }
```

i return something in `this.Item` which they pretty render in `Flatlist` but i can't call other functions of my component inside `this.item`! and i even can't point `this.props.navigation` or any other `this` key word inside that. i get undefined object error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use this.item in the FlatList component you need to bind this function to the class, you have 3 main ways to do that:

- in your constructor :

  ```
  contructor(props) {
      this.item = this.item.bind(this);
      // when using this.item everywhere, this will refer to the class in the method
  }
  ```
- if you are using the experimental public class fields syntax, you can use class fields to correctly bind callbacks :

  ```
  item = (data) => {
    //now this refer to the class
  }
  ```
- Or directly in the component:

  ```
  <FlatList
      ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
      data={this.state.foods}
      extraData={this.state}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={(data) => this.item(data)}
      horizontal
      onEndReached={(x) => { this.loadMore() }}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  />
  ```

i prefer the second way