# How to use Flatlist for a simple array that is not an object?

Tags: react-native

I am learning to use Flatlist. I could use Flatlist to display the value of a key of an object nested in an array.

However, I couldn't use Flatlist for a simple array.

For example:

const arrayOfLetters = [A,B,C,D,E]

How to use Flatlist to display arrayOfLetters as

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E

Comment: React Native doesn't have a built-in way of doing this, you will need to add the numbers yourself. (i.e. using a for loop and concatenating to the string)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569402/how-to-call-other-functions-in-flat-list-render-function and this https://snack.expo.dev/@g1sm0/flatlist-play . Create a function to count up the index and pass everyloop a new item to render. this needs a lot of impovement.

Comment: We can just use the `index` prop here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `index` prop of the `renderItem` function to achieve what you want. Here is a working example.

```js
const array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView syle={{margin: 20}}>
      <FlatList data={array} renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return (<View>
          <Text style={{padding: 20}}>{index + 1}. {item}</Text>
        </View>)
      }} keyExtractor={(item) => item} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};
```

The above yields

[image]